# Best way to have default user settings in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, user-controls

I'm currently working on a RoR application where users are able to register and have a list of (lets say 20) image-formats. These image-formats have their own model. The admin of the website is able to add or remove formats. The users should be able to activate certain formats or deactivate.

I was thinking of just adding the 20 formats to the database for each user, but that wouldn't be flexible if the admin chooses to delete or add one. Their should be a more maintainable way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your explanation isn't very detailed. Especially I'm missing the "default" settings from the question.

First thing (easy one):
The Admin can create an entry for each format he wants to allow on the website. So there should be exactly one such entry in the table

Users can select from these formats several (up to a limit?) Why do they need to specially choose them? Can't they just use everything the admin allows? What would happen to uploaded images if the admin deletes a format?

Anyway, best would be a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship between the User and ImageFormat. Or another Model (UserImageFormat) that builds this bridge if any additional data is necessary.

For the case, that the Admin removes some formats, you can handle this in several ways. Either you add an "active" flag to the format record and then check for this each time you use the model or you actually just delete this record (in this case, make sure your associations are set with :`dependent => :destroy` so all the records that connect users to formats get destroyed too. (Write tests to ensure this)

Maybe you can find some gems or plugins that help with that. [This article](http://pivotallabs.com/users/nick/blog/articles/272-access-control-permissions-in-rails) may give you some more help. Maybe some of the authentication plugins can add access control. But I think your need (user can in some way influence what he can use/access) could be too special, since most gems for this kind of work will more likely address an admin centered access control.

Comment: Thanks for the informations and sorry for being not detailed enough. The main point is that there're 20 image formats which every user has access to and are active when they register. Therefore the default setting is: all formats are activated. The user still has te option to deactivate some formats, yet they can't delete or add formats (just the admin).

Comment: @Sweam, in this case I would go for the solution as I explained it. (I added a few details to my answer)

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong. But when the user registers there aren't any has_and_belongs_to_many relationships, although I'd like every new user to have the 20 formats activated. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Sweam: good point. Yes, in this case you would have to create them together with the user. (And create one for every user if the Admin adds a new format maybe).

Comment: Ok, thanks. But there this is the Rails way to do this? Seems very hard to maintain when you have a large userbase.

Comment: @Sweam, I don't think there is much about a "Rails way" to handle this kind of thing different from how you would setup your table structure for any other framework. Rails adds features like ":dependent => :destroy", which makes certain tasks more easy and reliable. But you want to store relations between users and image formats and there are not that many options. (See the link I added to my answer for some more ideas, how Rails can help)

Comment: Ok, Thanks, I'll try the HABTM then.